# "After file loaded" action

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-field, attachments, tinymce

I have a plug-in that allows for repeatable fields. There will be an image and the image description. The description allows for tinyMCE editing. There are obviously problems with this, but I think I have found a solution.

What I am trying to do is save the metadata after the user closes the thickbox and the image filed is populated. I'm wondering if there is an 'add_action' hook that I can use to accomplish this. Any ideas?

Comment: You could only do this with [tag:ajax]. Add an event handler. For a more detailed how-to, please refer to other questions tagged with [tag:ajax] and jQuery event handler and `.on( 'click', function()`s.

Comment: I actually ended up using the 'send_to_editor' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `send_to_editor` method in JavaScript. The end result ended up looking like this:

```
window.send_to_editor = function(html) { 
        // logic to save via AJAX goes here.
}
```